# Class method decorators

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am attempting to copy the functionality of the built-in `property` class / decorator; a very basic example of what I want to is this:

```py
# If a condition is met, run the first function, else, the second.

@godspeed()
def test():
    print(1, 2, 3, 4)

@test.else_()
def test():
    print(5, 6, 7, 8)
```

Here's what I have so far:

```py
import inspect

class godspeed_class():
    def __init__(
        self,
        func,
        args,
        kwargs,
        value,
    ):
        self.func = func
        self.args = args
        self.kwargs = kwargs
        self.value = value

    def __call__(self):
        if self.value:
            self.func(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
        else:
            self.else_func(*self.else_args, **self.else_kwargs)

    def else_(self, *args, **kwargs):
        def wrapper(func):
            self.else_func = func
            self.else_args = args
            self.else_kwargs = kwargs
        return wrapper

def godspeed(*args, value = 0, **kwargs):
    def wrapper(func):
        _ = godspeed_class(func, args, kwargs, value)
        inspect.stack(1)[1][0].f_globals[func.__name__] = _
    return wrapper
```

I already know how to implement the condition parsing, but I am having trouble with storing the function under the `else_` decorator in the class, so that I can call it if the condition isn't met.

In addition, despite injecting the new class directly into the global namespace, when I run `print(test)`, it tells me it's a `NoneType` object.

Note: Code has been updated; however, it still gives me the "`NoneType` object" error.

Comment: Shouldn't else_ return self? And why doesn't wrapper inside godspeed return the instance?

Comment: Unfortunately, I still haven't fully understood decorators for some reason; could you possibly explain to me what both would do?

Comment: Then I'd recommend running through a more structured introduction to them, starting with something less complicated until you understand what's happening. There's currently no reason to expect your code *would* work, and the use of inspect is baffling.

Comment: Ah; sorry, it took me some time to understand the comment. I'm using inspect to override the test function with a test class instance; is that not similar to what `property` does?

Comment: Not really, no. Property is a [descriptor](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html).

Comment: I know, but is it possible to achieve similar functionality?

Comment: In any case, I shall read up more on `descriptors`. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change both of your `wrapper` functions to return a callable object, probably the instance of your class. Otherwise you're going to have `None` as the value for the method, since the decorator syntax will assign the return value to the name of the decorated function, which means that even if your `inspect` hack works, it will get overwritten.

I'd suggest:

```
class godspeed_class():
    ...                       # __init__ and __call__ can remain the same

    def else_(self, *args, **kwargs):
        def wrapper(func):
            self.else_func = func
            self.else_args = args
            self.else_kwargs = kwargs
            return self                       # add return here
        return wrapper

def godspeed(*args, value = 0, **kwargs):
    def wrapper(func):
        return godspeed_class(func, args, kwargs, value) # and here (rather than inspect stuff)
    return wrapper
```

This will do the job for your example with a top-level `test` function. If you want to be able to decorate methods, you'll also need to add a `__get__` method to the class to add binding behavior (otherwise you'll not get the `self` argument passed in to the wrapped method).

It's a bit misleading to use `wrapper` as the name there, as the inner functions are the actual decorators being used here (the top level `godspeed` function and the `else_` method are decorator factories). Normally you use `wrapper` as a name of a function *returned* by a decorator (but you're using your class for that instead).

I'd also note that it's a bit strange that you're passing the arguments for the functions to the decorator factories, rather than having `__call__` accept arguments that it passes along to the relevant function. It's a bit unusual for a decorator that leaves behind a callable (rather than something like `property` that works differently) to dramatically change a function's calling convention, as it may end up hard for a caller to know what arguments they're expected to pass in, if the function signature isn't representative any more.

Comment: Thanks! I'm actually using a function as well as I don't know how to instantiate classes on the fly, without resorting to something like `instance = class()` or similar; returning them seems to be my best bet!

Answer (score 1):

A decorator is nothing magical. Basically, the `@decorator` syntax is just syntactic sugar, so this:

```
@mydecorator
def func(): 
    pass
```

is just a convenient shortcut for

```
def func():
    pass

func = mydecorator(func)
```

IOW, a "decorator" is a callable object that takes a callable as input and returns a callable (well, it's supposed to return a callable at least - you can actually return whatever, but then you'll break everyone's expectations).

Most often, the decorator is written as a simple function returning a closure over the decorated function:

```
def trace(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kw):
        result = func(*args, **kw)
        print("{}({}, {}) => {}". format(func, args, kw, result))
        return result

    return wrapper


@trace
def foo(x):
    return 42 * x
```

But (since closures are the poor man's classes and classes the poor man's closures) you can also implement it as a callable class, in which case the initializer will receive the decorated func, which in turn will be replaced by the instance:

```
class trace(object):
    def __init__(self, func):
        self.func = func

    def __call__(self, *args, **kw):
        result = self.func(*args, **kw)
        print("{}({}, {}) => {}". format(self.func, args, kw, result))
        return result



@trace
def foo(x):
    return 42 * x
```

Then you have "parameterized" decorators - the one that can take arguments. In this case you need two level of indirection, the top-level one (the one used as decorator) returning the actual decorator (the one that receives the function), ie:

```
def trace(out):
    def really_trace(func):
        def wrapper(*args, **kw):
            result = func(*args, **kw)
            out.write("{}({}, {}) => {}\n". format(func, args, kw, result))
            return result
        return wrapper
    return really_trace

@trace(sys.stderr)
def foo(x):
    return 42 * x
```

I leave the class-based implementation as an exercise to the reader ;-)

Now in your case, the fact that `test` ends up being `None` is quite simply due to the fact that your wrapper func forgets to return the `godspeed_class` instance as it should (instead messing with the function's `f_globals`, which, as you noticed, doesn't work as expected).

Since you didn't clearly explained what you're trying to achieve here ("something similar to `property`" isn't a proper spec), it's hard to provide a working solution, but as a starting point you may want to fix your `godspeed` func to behave as expected:

```
def godspeed(*args, value = 0, **kwargs):
    def wrapper(func):
        return godspeed_class(func, args, kwargs, value)

    return wrapper
```

Comment: Sorry about that! I was trying to create a decorator which can run a function based on temporary variables passed in to the decorator, and another function otherwise.